# How to generate a gaussian distribution intensity for an ROI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

I have an array `A` size of 64x64. An ROI region has pixels intensities is 100 if the pixels are inside ROI. Outside of ROI is zero

```
import numpy as np

A= np.zeros((64,64))
A[16:48,26:48]=100
```

I want to change the intensity value of inside ROI to a Gaussian distribution with the mean is 100 and variance is 1. How can I do it? I tried the below code but it is not correct because np.random.normal for whole array, instead of the ROI

```
noise_value = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=A.shape)
A = A*noise_value + A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region you're multiplying `noise_value` by needs to be the same shape as `noise_value`. Try:

```
A[16:48,26:48] = A[16:48,26:48] * noise_value + A[16:48,26:48]
```

also, your formula `A = A * noise_value + A`, doesn't seem to match the intensity distribution you describe.  If that's the case, you might just:

```
A = np.zeros((64,64))
A[16:48,26:48] = np.random.normal(100, 1, size=[32,22])
```

Comment: It is good idea. But what is happend if the ROI is not rectangular, i.e circle or some random shape `A[16:48,26:48] = np.random.normal(100, 1, size=[32,22])`

Comment: @John, if you want to support arbitrary shapes, you'll want to define your ROI with a position and a mask - which could be binary or more n alpha-channel to support various levels of transparency, which could be multiplied by your noise distribution and added.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gaus(x, a, m, s):
    return np.sqrt(a)*np.exp(-(x-m)**2/(2*s**2))
    # if you want it normalized:
    #return 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*s**2))*np.exp(-(x-m)**2/(2*s**2))                               

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(100), np.arange(100))

gaus2d = gaus(xx, 100, 50, 10)*gaus(yy, 100, 50, 10)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(gaus2d) 
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]